# ROR + Access Cookie Value Assigned by RubyCode in Javascript Function

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, cookies

Is there any way to access Cookie value assigned in RUBY Code at Javascript Function.

Code in Ruby

```
cookies[:url] = { :value => request.url }
```

Javascript Code:

```
var cookieURL = document.cookie;
```

But I want simple URL like

```
http://localhost:3000/profile?id=12
```

I am getting some decoded URL. Now I wanna access the cookie value in Javascript code.
 Please suggest something. ??

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your javascript.

```
var cookieURL = document.cookie; 
// - - > "url=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fhome"

//removes the "url=" portion
cookieURL = cookieURL.slice(4);

//decodes the URI
var decoded = decodeURIComponent(cookieURL);

alert(decoded); // - - > http://localhost:3000/home
```

This code is working here: http://jsbin.com/ubudo4